# Managed packages for 2 factor authentication / Pin creation on a lightning out application for the guest profile users who are unauthorized in the org

Tags: lightning

Hi are there any managed packages that would enable 2 factor authentication on a lightning out application for the guest profile users ?

We have a lightning application on our client website. After filling some of the details we wanted to give them option to create a pin or any other authorization just like creating an account to complete the further form/application. This should be unique to every user. SO whenever they logged in back they don't have to start over again each time.

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions, especially under different accounts. Instead, log in and make edits to improve your existing posts so they can be answered. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidReed  I was unable to get into that account for some reason so had to post it again. Thanks. Can you please remove the duplicate tag